# How to use negative lookahead in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match everything except this

```
/^_.*\.scss$/i
```

I tried this

```
/^(?!_.*\.scss).*$/i
```

but it did **not** match on

```
_dsdfsdfsdf.scss.sd
```

I think its because the regex says you only can't start with that. But in this case, it should match this.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Add an end-of-string anchor `$`? Rather, why didn't you include it in the lookahead in the first place? It was already present in the original regex...

Comment: What do you mean? I do have it on the regex.

Comment: Actually this worked `/^(?!_.*\.scss$).*$/i`

Comment: It should be inside of the lookahead. Why did you put everything _except_ the `$` into the lookahead? Of course it doesn't work correctly if you only negate a part of your regex instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Why do you need to negate the match inside of the regex? Why not just `if (!/\.scss$/i.test(str))`?